# Remove the blank space around the .svg image using Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg

Is it possible to remove the blank space around the `.svg` image using Inkscape?

For example, here is the image I have:
[image]

Here is what it looks like when I use it in css:
[image]

As you can see I am having that blank space around the image.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having selected the actual image and going to *File → Document Properties  → Resize page to content  → Resize page to drawing or selection* worked.

Comment: I removed a bunch of comments because they didn’t go anywhere and were [not nice](/conduct). Iamyourfriend: You can still improve your answer by [edit]ing it and add some explanation.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, ok, thank you. You can delete the comment as well after you read it. I do not think that I did something wrong or offended anyone here. I just conducted a constructive dialog. I would be fine to accept that I am wrong in the conversation if it would have been proven. But it was not, so it was the reason why I persisted to push back. Thank you again.

Comment: With current Inkscape, this is even faster: Edit -> Resize page to selection (or Shift + Ctrl + R)